# How to get ID from master table then record to details table

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, master-detail

I'm junior in MVC programming I have this code in controller:

```
     [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveOrder(PonudiVM O)
        {
            bool status = false;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (leskaEntities dc = new leskaEntities())
                {

                    ponudi ponuda1 = new ponudi { klID = O.klient, datum = O.datum, description = O.description };
                    foreach (var i in O.DetalnaPonuda)
                    {
                        ponuda1.ponudaDet.Add(i);

                    }

                    dc.ponudi.Add(ponuda1);
                    dc.SaveChanges();

                    //int last_id = db.ponudi.Max(item => item.pID);
                    status = true;
                }
            }
                catch (BllException bllEx)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", bllEx.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //todo da se zapise vo LOG file
            }
        }
            else
            {
                status = false;
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
        }
```

What I need to add in the code, to take new ID from master table then record ID to details table.

My data I send by Javascript and jQuery.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last id simply do:

```
dc.ponudi.Add(ponuda1);
dc.SaveChanges();

int last_id = ponuda1.id;
```

If the detail table is ponudaDet, by the association, the ID should be already saved.